# from azure.monitor.query import ApplicationInsightsDataClient ImportError: can't import name 'ApplicationInsightsDataClient' from 'azure.monitor.query

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service

Trying to import the ApplicationInsightsDataClient package from azure.monitor.query, but still obtain an error. Is there another package available or a way to get this working using an appropriate command or download from pip?

Error Received:

```
from azure.monitor.query import ApplicationInsightsDataClient
ImportError: cannot import name 'ApplicationInsightsDataClient' from 'azure.monitor.query'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from azure.monitor.query import ApplicationInsightsDataClient
ImportError: cannot import name 'ApplicationInsightsDataClient' from 'azure.monitor.query'
```

***ApplicationInsightsDataClient** is part of **azure-applicationinsights** Python package. And **azure-applicationinsights** package is **deprecated** and **replaced** with **azure-monitor-query** python package.*

**Refer here:-**

[azure.applicationinsights.application_insights_data_client module | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-applicationinsights/azure.applicationinsights.application_insights_data_client?view=azure-python)

***I tried the code below with azure.monitor.query and got the same error:-***

[image]

Also, [azure-monitor-query](https://pypi.org/project/azure-monitor-query/) does not have application_insights_data_client module and its replacement is using LogsQueryClient to query the logs of application insights, azure monitor.

***When I tried the same code with azure-applicationinsights it worked like below:-***

```py
from  azure.identity  import  DefaultAzureCredential

from  azure.applicationinsights  import  ApplicationInsightsDataClient

from  azure.applicationinsights.operations.query_operations  import  QueryOperations

  

credential = DefaultAzureCredential()

client = ApplicationInsightsDataClient(credential)

  

print(client)
```

**Output:-**

[image]

As this package is deprecated you can query the telemetry data by using the code below with azure.monitor.query package:-

**Code:-**

```py
import os
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime, timezone
from azure.monitor.query import LogsQueryClient, LogsQueryStatus
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
from azure.core.exceptions import HttpResponseError

credential = DefaultAzureCredential()
client = LogsQueryClient(credential)
LOG_WORKSPACE_ID = "<workspace-id>"

query = """AppMetrics | take 5"""

start_time=datetime(2021, 7, 2, tzinfo=timezone.utc)
end_time=datetime(2021, 7, 4, tzinfo=timezone.utc)

try:
    response = client.query_workspace(
        workspace_id=LOG_WORKSPACE_ID,
        query=query,
        timespan=(start_time, end_time)
        )
    if response.status == LogsQueryStatus.PARTIAL:
        error = response.partial_error
        data = response.partial_data
        print(error)
    elif response.status == LogsQueryStatus.SUCCESS:
        data = response.tables
    for table in data:
        df = pd.DataFrame(data=table.rows, columns=table.columns)
        print(df)
except HttpResponseError as err:
    print("something fatal happened")
    print (err)
```

**Output:-**

[image]

**Log analytics output:-**

[image]

**Reference:-**

[azure-monitor-query · PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/azure-monitor-query/#examples)